# Dynamic localization in swift

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I am doing dynamic localization. I am getting all localization string from server end. On the basis of response i am creating dynamic localization.string file. For eg:

```
"By Venue"="Par Lieu";
"Invitee Name"="Invité Nom";
"Email suffix:"="Email suffixe:";
"METRICS"="MESURES";
"MD - Moldova"="MD - Moldavie";
"Name:"="Nom:";
"Approval Manager"="Gestionnaire de Approbation";
"Last login on:"="Dernière connexion sur:";
```

But in this response there are also some HTML tags are included. For eg:

```
"<b ljsid-1="">Note:</b> You can send this email manually once every 24 hours."="<b ljsid-1="">Remarque:</b> Vous pouvez envoyer cet e-mail manuellement une fois toutes les 24 heures.";
```

If i remove this tag from dynamic created localized file then i am able to do loclaization. Otherwise i can't loclaization.

So please suggest me, how to handle this HTML tags. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To get text out from HTML you can use [Kanna](https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna) in your project. In the following snippet `test.txt` is just a file with your HTML string as a source.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        do {
            let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType: "txt")
            let str = try String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            // Use Kanna framework to get HTML text
            if let doc = HTML(html: str, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                let text = doc.text
                print(text)

                let file = "/output.txt"

                if let dirs : [String] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) {
                    var path = dirs[0] //documents directory
                    path.appendContentsOf(file)

                    //writing
                    try text!.writeToFile(path, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding);

                    //reading
                    let text2 = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                    print(text2)
                }

            }

        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }
```

The output is:

```
Optional("\"Note: You can send this email manually once every 24 hours.\"=\"Remarque: Vous pouvez envoyer cet e-mail manuellement une fois toutes les 24 heures.\"")
"Note: You can send this email manually once every 24 hours."="Remarque: Vous pouvez envoyer cet e-mail manuellement une fois toutes les 24 heures."
```